# How to rename files in batch with Unix rename command?

Tags: linux, unix, perl, rename

I have files whose names look like this:

```
Sim1-2_40.36.chr20_sb.foo.indel.novoalign.sam
Sim1-2_40.36.chr20_sb.foo.indel.bwa.sam
```

What I want to do is to replace all `indel` with `snp` in the names
yielding

```
Sim1-2_40.36.chr20_sb.foo.snp.novoalign.sam
Sim1-2_40.36.chr20_sb.foo.snp.bwa.sam
```

But why does this unix command not work?

```
$ rename 's/indel/snp/' *.sam
```

Comment: I can't see the documentation for rename mentioning support for commands like 's/indel/snp/' , which rename utility are you using ?

Comment: Looks like the OP is referring to http://man.cx/prename

Comment: What `doesn't work` about that command? Are you getting an error? Is it not changing the filenames? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

Because you’re using the wrong rename program.  [This is the right one.](http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename)

Comment: If it isn't on CPAN ([1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/bin/rename.PL), [2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Rename/rename.PL), [3](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-PerlMove/script/pmv), [4](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlmv/bin/perlmv), [5](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-FileTools-BulkRename/bin/brn)), it might as well not exist.

Comment: @daxim: CPAN hates programs.

Comment: You're unreasonable.

Answer (score 4):

The "normal" `rename` utility (part of `util-linux`) takes 3 or more arguments (as mentioned in TFM..)

```
rename FROM TO filespec...
```

Thus, you are (probably) looking for:

```
rename .indel. .snp. *.sam
```

Test this on a scratch directory first, as you may be using the another implementation of `rename`.

Or check the man page.  *cough*

Comment: +1 for not immediately jumping to regexes.  :)  But you might want dots around your `indel` and `snp`, so paths like `blah.stuffindelsomeotherstuff.x` don't get changed as well.

Comment: Good point.  Added.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -1 | while read item
do
  mv $item $(echo $item|sed -e s/.indel./.snp./g);
done
```

Comment: Why `ls -1 | while read item` rather than `for item in *.sam`?

Comment: @user280476: your code will do strange things if you have files with spaces in the name.

Comment: … or a large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

`rename` doesn't do `sed`-style substitutions.  This very short Perl script will let you do `regmv *.sam s/indel/snp/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# regmv - Rename files using a regular expression
#
# This program renames files by using a regular expression to
# determine their new name.
#
# Usage: regmv file [file ...] regexp
#
# $Id: regmv,v 1.1 1998/10/14 17:07:55 blrfl Exp $
#

sub at_clean()
{
    my $message = $@;
    $message =~ s|\s+at /.*$||s;
    return $message;
}

(@ARGV > 1)
    || die "Usage: regmv [options] file [file ...] regexp\n";

my $expr = pop @ARGV;

$_ = 'SomeValue';
eval "\$_ =~ $expr";
die "Yuck: " . at_clean() if $@;

foreach (@ARGV)
{
    my $old = $_;

    eval "\$_ =~ $expr";

    next if $_ eq $old;

    (rename $old, $_)
        || die "Rename failed: $!\n";
}
```